# Pasar objeto por (ngModelChange) Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Como podría pasar mi objeto "item" que está en el for del "mat-option" a la directiva (ngModelChange), necesito poder tener este objeto en mi función "onChangeServicio", lo unico que logro pasar por ahí ese solo el valor de [value].

Comparto el codigo.

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <mat-select placeholder="Servicios" formControlName="codServicio" (ngModelChange)="onChangeServicio($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of dataServicio" [value]="item.id">
      {{item.id + ' - ' + item.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
  <mat-error *ngIf="formGrupNewRequerimiento.get('codServicio').hasError('min')">
    Campo Obligatorio
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Agradezco cualquier sugerencia.

Answer (score 2):

`(ngModelChange)` pasa a la función que le indiqués un objeto `$event` con el valor de `[value]` que tenga el `option` seleccionado.

Una respuesta rápida puede ser cambiar el `[value]` para que contenga el `item` completo:

```
...
<mat-select placeholder="Servicios" formControlName="codServicio" (ngModelChange)="onChangeServicio($event)">
   <mat-option *ngFor="let item of dataServicio" [value]="item">
     {{item.id + ' - ' + item.name}}
   </mat-option>
</mat-select>
...
```